# Using postgresql server-side cursors when using sqlachemy orm

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am searching for the correct syntax for using server-side cursors when using the orm version (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#creating-a-session) of sqlaclhemy.

E.g.

```
session = SessionMaker()
res = session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.date.between(odate, cdate))

for obj in res:
    append_to_disk(obj)
```

I've tried:

```
stream_sessionmaker = sessionmaker(
    pg_engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True)
)
session = stream_sessionmaker()
```

to no avail. The documentation seams to only document the Core version (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.stream_results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`yield_per`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per):

```
res = session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.date.between(odate, cdate)).yield_per(1000)
```